# java counter in string pyramid

Tags: java, for-loop

I'm trying to create an inverted pyramid with a string. The loop subtracts a character from each end. Only the right side of it is being subtracted. How do I get it to do the same for the left side? How can I also get it to print the length of each line correctly?

```
     int x = 0;

     int space = ' ';

     space = space + ' ';  

     int counter = fullName.length();

     for( x = 0; x < fullName.length()/2; x++ )
     {

         System.out.println( counter - x + " [" + fullName.substring( x, fullName.length() - x ) + "]" );

     }
```

Answer (score 2):

`String#substring` does not replace the inner data of the `String` variable. Remember that a `String` instance is immutable.

You should print a `String spaces` variable before printing the `fullName` in order to add whitespaces:

```
String spaces = ""
for( x = 0; x < fullName.length()/2; x++ ) {
    System.out.println(spaces + fullName.substring(x, fullName.length()-x));
    spaces = spaces + " ";
}
```

Comment: So do `fullName = fullName.substring...;` before your print, then your print statement can just say `fullName` as opposed to fullName.substring...`

Comment: Or use something like `StringBuilder`

Comment: @MadProgrammer for the OP's code, I could guess (and hope I'm right) that he/she's in learning phase, so no need to bother him/her with `StringBuilder`s (yet).

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza No probs, it's only suggestion ;), you're answer is still valid with out it

Answer (score 0):

If you're going for something that looks like this:

```
triangle
 riangl
  iang
   an
```

you'll want to be sure to add spaces to the beginning of what you print in addition to removing text from the end of what you print.

```
for( x = 0; x < fullName.length()/2; x++ ) {
    System.out.print(counter - x + " [");
    for(int y = 0; y < x; y++) {
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
    System.out.println(fullName.substring( x, fullName.length() - x ) + "]" );
}
```