# pyramid and counter in Java

Tags: java, for-loop

I have this inverted pyramid:

```
     String spaces = "";

         int x =0;
             int counter = fulllName.length();

         for( x = 0; x < fullName.length()/2; x++ ) 
         {
             System.out.println(counter-x + "[" + spaces + fullName.substring(x, fullName.length()-x) + "]");
             spaces = spaces + " ";
         }
```

And I want to make it print the length of each line in the beginning of each line but as part of the pyramid itself. I also want to enclose each line in brackets [ ] but with the length of the line outside of the brackets. When I try to, it prints like this:

```
     7[ 1111111]
     7[  11111]
     7[   111]
     7[    1]
```

and I want something like this:

```
    7[1111111]
     5[11111]
      3[111]
       1[1]
        0[]
```

Comment: You must print spaces before the counter. Based on your last question, you should make some tests of your code before coming here waiting for us doing your job: [java counter in string pyramid](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12683878/1065197).

Answer (score 2):

Just replace `counter-x + "[" + spaces` with `spaces + counter-x + "["` in the print statement.

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't it be:

```
spaces + fullName.length()-x + "[" + fullName.substring(x, fullName.length()-x + "]"
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
for( x = 0; x < fullName.length()/2; x++ ) 
{
     System.out.println(counter-x + "[" + spaces + fullName.substring(x, fullName.length()-x) + "]");
     spaces = spaces + " ";
}
```

To

```
for( x = 0; x < fullName.length()/2; x++ ) 
{
   System.out.println(spaces + counter-x + "[" + fullName.substring(x, full Name.length()-x) + "]");
   spaces = spaces + " ";
}
```

Comment: `spaces` should go before `(counter-x)`.

Answer (score 1):

you have spaces within brackets, your println() should be:

```
System.out.println(spaces + (counter - x) + "[" + fullName.substring(x, fullName.length() - x) + "]");
```

Comment: I shouldn't check emails during posting answers, now I'm the last one :)